# Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature

Tags: azure, azure-storage

When using the Azure Storage API to access file services, we are getting the following errors.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
  <Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
  <Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature. RequestId:5a7f5ef2-a01a-0023-134e-436c77000000 Time:2021-05-07T14:36:32.7067133Z</Message>
  <AuthenticationErrorDetail>Unversioned authenticated access is not allowed.</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
</Error>
```

We've followed the documentation and believe we have all the correct headers but obviously missing something.

Signature string we're encoding:

```
GET\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-date:Fri, 07 May 2021 15:29:49 GMT\nx-ms-version:2020-04-08\n/*our_azure_resource*\ncomp:metadata
```

Code using CryptoJS that we're using to do the encoding

```js
let signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(stringToSign).toString(), this.key)
                        .toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
```

Value of Authorization header:

```
SharedKey storageaccountname:decodedstring
```

Comment: Can you share the request headers?

Comment: Hi @GauravMantri the request headers would just be the following, as we're providing the value of `x-ms-date` within the signature

`Authorization: SharedKey storageaccountname:decodedstring`

Comment: @bengrah Please add `x-ms-version:2020-04-08` in your HTTP  request header.

Answer (score 2):

According to my test, we need to use the following code to do sign with package `crypto-js`

```
const str = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(
  inputvalue,
  CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(accountKey)
);
const sig = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(str);
```

For example

1. install package

```
npm i crypto-js request xml2js
```

2. Code(list containers)

```
var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");
var request = require("request");
var parseString = require("xml2js").parseString;
const methodName = "GET";
const accountName = "andyprivate";
const accountKey =
  "";

const date = new Date().toUTCString();
const version = "2020-04-08";

const inputvalue =
  methodName +
  "\n" /*VERB*/ +
  "\n" /*Content-Encoding*/ +
  "\n" /*Content-Language*/ +
  "\n" /*Content-Length*/ +
  "\n" /*Content-MD5*/ +
  "\n" /*Content-Type*/ +
  "\n" /*Date*/ +
  "\n" /*If-Modified-Since*/ +
  "\n" /*If-Match*/ +
  "\n" /*If-None-Match*/ +
  "\n" /*If-Unmodified-Since*/ +
  "\n" /*Range*/ +
  "x-ms-date:" +
  date +
  "\n" +
  "x-ms-version:" +
  version +
  "\n" +
  "/" +
  accountName +
  "/" +
  "\ncomp:list";
console.log(inputvalue);
const str = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(
  inputvalue,
  CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(accountKey)
);
const sig = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(str);

const options = {
  method: "GET",
  url: `https://${accountName}.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=list`,
  headers: {
    "x-ms-date": date,
    "x-ms-version": version,
    Authorization: "SharedKey " + accountName + ":" + sig,
  },
};
request(options, function (error, response) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);
  parseString(response.body, (error, result) => {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);
    const res = JSON.stringify(result);
    console.log(res);
  });
});
```

[image]

For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key).

Comment: Hi @JimXu

It looks like we're doing almost the same thing except you've not UTF8 encoded the signature string first, so is this even required in your view?

Thanks,

Comment: @bengrah I think it is not required?

Comment: Not according to this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authorize-with-shared-key#encoding-the-signature)

Comment: @bengrah Sorry i cannot understand

Comment: Hi Jim, it says on the documentation that you need to


 _...call the HMAC-SHA256 algorithm on the UTF-8-encoded signature string and encode the result as Base64. Note that you also need to Base64-decode your storage account key._

From that I'm inferring you have to

1. UTF8 encode the signature
2. Run the SHA256 algorithm on top of the UTF8 encoded version of the signature
3. Encode the result of that as Base64

But I can see you don't use UTF8 encoding in your example, so is this something that's required?

Comment: @bengrah. I misunderstand your word. You can uft8 encode the string you use to sign.

Comment: @bengrah The code should be like `const str = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(
  CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(inputvalue),
  CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(accountKey)
);`.

Comment: @bengrah Could you please provide your entire error?

Comment: @bengrah please use the `CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify()` to base64 enode your signature after running the code `signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256`

Comment: OK, I've done that, I end up with something like this:

`SharedKey user:thB54rQGo4r0dFhJ/Ad+we24dMy90q2qk14Y9DncafFNI=`

But still getting the same error:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:84661e84-001a-0043-3271-452955000000
Time:2021-05-10T07:51:57.0831319Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>Unversioned authenticated access is not allowed.</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>`

Comment: @bengrah Could you please provide the whole code about how to create share key and call request?

Comment: Sure  

    let verb = method.toUpperCase();
    let utcNow = new Date()
    utcNow.setHours(new Date().getHours() + 1)
    let finalutc = utcNow.toUTCString();

    let stringToSign =
      verb +                                                          
      this.newlines +                                                       
      "x-ms-date:" + finalutc + "\n" +                                               
      "x-ms-version:2020-04-08\n" +                                            
      "/location/\ncomp:list"

Comment: let signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(stringToSign), CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(this.key))
    let finalsignature = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(signature)

Comment: @bengrah Is that you use the account key to do sign.

Comment: @bengrah  I test your code. It is ok for me/

Comment: Good sign! Still doing some testing here.

Comment: @bengrah Could you please check if your the formate of your stringtosign? It should be like https://i.stack.imgur.com/A49pL.png

Comment: @bengrah Besides, could you please tell me how to send the HTTP request?

Comment: Hi @Jim Xu - I've made a few changes and gotten further, I'm using _Postman_ - I've added in your suggested headers. Now getting the following message:

</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>Cannot find the claimed account when trying to GetProperties for the account accountname.</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>

Comment: @bengrah Could you please tell me which API you call

Comment: "https://" + accountName + ".file.core.windows.net/?comp=list"

Comment: @bengrah Could you please check if your account name is right?

Comment: @bengrah Could you please provide the screenshoot of how you call the rest API?